# Flask Web app not rendering on PythonAnywhere

Tags: python-3.x, flask, pythonanywhere

I am trying to host a Flask web app on python anywhere but I cannot get the website to render. When I visit the link, all I get is a web page saying `Hello from Flask!`. My error log does not show any message. I am lost and don't know what to do. I made a simple test Flask app in the same directory to test whether it was the domain host, or an import issue, but the test app worked fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you have a look at the documentation? There is a whole section on Flask that contains very detailed information on how to deploy your website, including a [beginner's guide](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/121/). The message `Hello from Flask!` actually shows that your app is indeed running correctly, this is the default app behavior.

Comment: Thanks  @SébastienLavoie. I was not aware of this beginner's guide. Your comment and the guide made me realize that my default actual app.py was replaced with the default app.py. If you post your comment as an answer i will gladly accept it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In PythonAnywhere's documentation, there is a whole section on Flask that contains detailed information on how to deploy your website, including a [beginner's guide](https://blog.pythonanywhere.com/121/). The message `Hello from Flask!` actually shows that your app is indeed running correctly, this is the default app behavior.

Once you get your app going, you may also be interested in the following resources in the help pages to supplement your learning:

- [General flask tips, including avoiding app.run() and how to run database config with db.create_all()](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask)
- [Dealing with a 504 error in Flask applications](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask504Error)
- [Using SQLAlchemy with MySQL](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/UsingSQLAlchemywithMySQL)
- [How to scale a Flask Application on PythonAnywhere with Memcache](https://blog.memcachier.com/2018/10/01/flask-on-pythonanywhere-tutorial/)
- [Installing new Python modules for yourself](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/InstallingNewModules)

Comment: It feels like my birthday with all these resources! Thanks a bunch i will be diving into them shortly.

Comment: You're welcome! More generally, you can skim through the [main help page](https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/) where you will find more info to help you debug your app and tutorials explaining how to use the different features available on PythonAnywhere. It's extensive and really approachable, making it a great resource to start working on new aspects of your app when you're ready!